# Do I need to create SSH keys (AWS) when I already have Key-Pairs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

Whats the difference between AWS Key-pairs and SSH keys ? are they same ? if not why do we need SSH keys, I already have created key pairs while deploying a sample app.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that AWS manages their key pairs and sets up the EC2 machines so you can connect using them.

You always have to set an AWS key pair (n.b. you can upload your own SSH keys instead of having AWS create one for you).

You are free to configure your EC2 instances so that you can use additional ssh keys if you want, but you have to manage this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create AWS SSH keys in order to connect to your EC2 instance.

AWS provides you with a couple of options:

1. Create SSH keys managed by them. Saves you the overhead of creating them yourself with OpenSSL or something of the likes.
2. Upload your own pair of keys which would be the option for your case. Just upload them and while creating the EC2 instance you can choose to use the uploaded pair
3. You can create the EC2 instance without providing SSH Keys. This is in a case where you wouldn't want to connect to the instance via SSH.

**NOTE**: You cannot attach/change SSH keys to your EC2 instance once created, unless you take an apporach of removing the ROOT volume and ... it is actually too much overhead, but you can read more on the matter here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair. You would rather create new instance though.

In a few simple words: AWS Keys are SSH keys managed by AWS itself as @thomasmichaelwallace mentioned and they do not differ from keys you can generate yourself by any means